# FQL query on stream table returns empty using created_time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a FQL query for the stream table as follows

```sql
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key ='nf' AND created_time < 1335500000
```

Where the `filter_key` grabs the news feed. This query returns no data (for my account)

Where as, this query (using unix set at April 30 2012)

```sql
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key ='nf' AND created_time < 1335758400
```

Returns data.

I can keep pushing the unix time back to a point until it just stops showing data, yet there is data there from just browsing my news feed manually through the Facebook UI.

The [`stream`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) docs state

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as `created_time` along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

So to me, it means I can do "pagination" with created_time and limit.

This isn't the case.

Even using the alternative [`/me/home`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home) returns the first set but when I use the pagination links there is no data returned.

Is there something I missing here? Maybe some explanation as to why the previous data is empty for both the FQL and Graph API calls?

Comment: I have same doubt, do you solve this problem?